# Specify which ambient `lib` a type should come from

Tags: typescript

I'm using `window.onmessage` in TypeScript. VS Code seems to think that the parameter has the type `MessageEvent` from `lib.dom.iterable.d.ts` while it should have the type `MessageEvent` from `lib.dom.d.ts`. How can I point the compiler/language service to the correct type?

Answer (score 0):

`MessageEvent` is an interface, so TypeScript merges its different definitions. It just happens that VS Code is pointing you to `lib.dom.iterable.d.ts`, but in reality any value of type `MessageEvent` you come across should implement the contract defined in `lib.dom.d.ts`.